# Redux state structure best practices

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm a beginner in React/Redux and I went through tons of similar topics, but none of them answers my question :-/

Let's say I'm going to build a project management app. There is a list of projects, each project can have a list of meetings, both project and meeting can have a list of tasks or documents. Every entity in the app (project, meeting, task, ...) can have a list of tags for filtering purposes.

Now my question - how to structure the Redux store for this kind of an app? Is it a good approach to keep all data in the store or is it better to load only data that are needed for current view on demand (from API) and keep it outside of the store?

For me, it seems to be nice to have all the data in the store, push changes to it (eg. via WebSockets) and use only selectors to display what is needed, but I cannot imagine keeping eg. thousands of entities in Redux store.

Comment: Try to have your state data normalized (https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr explains how normalized data look like). You can then use `reselect` library to "unnormalize" the data and get full entity tree. As for what to store in your state, you will have to decide where is the line of what still makes sense and when there is just too much data. It depends on both entity count and size of one entity, but generally if there is 1k+ items you should start thinking about having only "some" entities in state.

Comment:  Martin, that could even be an answer. I would add that if you only have some of the data in store, you can dispatch actions to load the needed data from your views.

Comment: Yep, the store is normalized, it would be a nightmare to manage so nested structures :-D